# Control-M Job Execution status

Tags: control-m

Is there any way in Control-M to pass the execution of the job without running the script?

Suppose i have passed all the parameters required for execution of job i.e. File Path, File Name , Node Id, Parameters but i want to run the job as dummy one but still want to successfully execute it and make it in green status.

Can we specify any command in Job Scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, select 'dummy' as type of job and there is no need to pass command line to dummy job. It will get completed as soon as it gets the resource and you can use it as trigger for another job.

Regards,
Sahil Kondel

Answer (score 0):

You can force set job OK in post-processing to get Green/Success status